# VBA Code for Conditional Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a conditional loop macro in Excel. Column B contains a last name, Column C contains a first name, and Column D contains a first and last name. I am trying to get the macro to detect when Column D = Column C + Column B.

If D = C + B, then clear contents of D.

So, the following works for a single row:

```
Sub ClearContentsD ()

If Range("D1").Value = Range("C1").Value + Space(1) + Range("B1") Then Range("D1").ClearContents

End Sub
```

It does not work without the added Space(1), and I cannot get it to loop through the whole worksheet:

```
Sub ClearContentsLoop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count

    Next i

Do While Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value + Space(1) + Cells(i, 2).Value
Cells(i, 4).ClearContents

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

VBA doesn't like my Do While. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CJ

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the code is working with?

Comment: *VBA doesn't like my Do While* is not a problem description unless you tell us specificall what *VBA*  doesn't **like**. What does that mean **specifically**?

Comment: Also if you want "John Smith" to equal "John" + "Smith", you will need a space unless the cell value includes a space after "John ".

Comment: `"John Smith"` does not equal `"John" + "Smith"`.  In VBA `+` is only used for arithmetic.  You want `"John" & "Smith"` since `&` is the concatenation operator.

Comment: Do you plan on using the `For i = 1` loop? I don't think an `i` value is ever assigned?

Comment: You have a `For Loop` that counts from `1 To Rows.Count` (but does nothing else) leaving `i` with a value of `Rows.Count + 1`.  You then have a `Do Loop` that tests values on row `i`.  But row `i` does not exist.  My guess is your `Do Loop` should be an `If` inside the `For Loop`.

Comment: @TonyDallimore makes an excellent point that I missed, but you will still need a space to make the concatenation work.

Comment: The `+` actually works for this code since he has added the `space(1)` in his code, but it is bad code, so it should be updated. Just thought I would note it.

Comment: @Histerical.  Whoops!  I notices the `+` but forgot the `" "` so "John" + " " + "Smith" or something simple variation.

Comment: @Histerical.  You are correct, `+` works for me with Excel 2016.  I cannot find anything in the documentation to justify this and I am sure it did not work with Excel 2003 which is the last version I used.  It will be Friday before I can find a copy of 2003 but I will report back when I can test this properly.

Comment: @TonyDallimore gets it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You must concatenate strings with `&`. The plus (`+`) is for addition;
- Your `For` loop is not doing anything: its body is empty;
- Your `Do While` Loop will at most run once, because `i` is not incremented;
- It is a mystery why you would want two loops (`For` and `Do While`);
- A sheet has many rows of which you only use a fraction, so don't loop through all of them (`For`) and use `UsedRange`.

Possible correction:

```
Sub ClearContentsLoop()
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value Then
            Cells(i, 4).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I tried using an If/Then function first with no success, but my it wouldn't work with my empty loop and (+) function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to ignore the space in the values you are evaluating.  Try this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, 4).Value, Cells(i, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Cells(i, 4).Value, Cells(i, 3).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Cells(i, 4).ClearContents
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**Explanation:**

By using the **InStr** function, you are testing for the presence of one text string inside of another, and if at least one match is found, then the function returns a non-zero value (the position where the match was found). In the above example, you are testing for the presence of the first name and last name at the same time, and if both are found, then the code clears out the contents of the cell.

And, as was pointed out in the comments section, you need to do this inside the loop so that all cells down the length of the worksheet are evaluated and updated as specified.

Be sure to test this on a COPY of your original data so that you don't lose the original values in case you want to roll back your changes!  ;)